# CakePHP 3 - beforeSave callback not working on edit

Tags: cakephp, callback, edit, cakephp-3.0

I have a `beforeSave`-callback which is called just fine whenever I create a new entity. However when I am editing, it's not called at all.
Could not find anything in the documentation that could be helpful.

Here's my edit function:

```
public function edit($id = null) {
    if (!$id) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid article'));
    }

    $article = $this->Articles->get($id);
    if ($this->request->is(['post', 'put'])) {
        $this->Articles->patchEntity($article, $this->request->data);
        if ($this->Articles->save($article)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('Your article has been updated.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to update your article.'));
    }

    $this->set('article', $article);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that your save operation does make it that far in the first place? ie, is it succesfull? Because if it is, then I would kinda doubt that the event is not being dispatched, as this happens in one and the same method for insert as well as updates.

Comment: Please post the code of your `beforeSave`-callback too.

Comment: I am sure cause the record is modified. Inside my beforeSave I am simply calling a die(), so there's not way it's calling it without me noticing.

Comment: Well, if the record is being saved, then the event is being dispatched, unless the dispatcher is broken. Check whether the `$this->Articles` instance is really an instance of your actual table class (`debug(get_class($this->Articles))`) that has the callback method implemented, and not an "auto-table" (instance of `Cake\ORM\Table`), also make sure that you're not messing with [**`Table::implementedEvents()`**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.0.1/src/ORM/Table.php#L2202).

Comment: Will check later tonight and get back at you.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: @ndm $this->Articles is instance of 'App\Model\Table\ArticlesTable'. Seems ok to me.
I didn't touch the Table's implementedEvents.

Comment: Well, then I'm stumped. You'll have to do some further debugging on your own, hack your way into the core to check where in the save operation things are going wrong.

Answer (score 14):

The `beforeSave` function will be triggered only if the data you post/edit is modified.

```
//triggers only if an entity has been modified
public function beforeSave(Event $event, Entity $entity)
{
    if($entity->isNew()) {       
        //on create
    } else {
        //on update
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm unsure who down-voted this answer as its essentially true.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the problem that the tutorial got stuck on this point, but I used the bin/cake bake command to autogenerate the ArticlesTable code and it added this validator:

```
$validator
        ->scalar('slug')
        ->maxLength('slug', 191)
        /*->requirePresence('slug', 'create')*/
        ->notEmptyString('slug')
        ->add('slug', 'unique', ['rule' => 'validateUnique', 'provider' => 'table']);
```

When I commented the requirePresence() it solved this issue for me. If you have requirePresence('fieldName', 'create') for validation, you will get an error if you don't have that field on a post when creating the new Article entity.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your need use `Event` and `Entity` object:

check this example:

```
// src/Model/Table/ArticlesTable.php

use Cake\Event\Event;
use Cake\ORM\Entity;

public function beforeSave(Event $event, Entity $entity) {
    if ($entity->isNew()) {
        return true;
    }
    // edit code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to write the same code:

```
public function beforeSave(\Cake\Event\Event $event, \Cake\ORM\Entity $entity, \ArrayObject $options){

    if($entity->isNew()) {
        // on create
    } else {
        // on update
    } 
}
```